# Como conectarme a postgresql y MySQL desde C#

Tags: c#

Buenas noches, como me puedo conectar a una base de datos en MySQL y otra en postgresql utilizando C#, algunos ejemplos o enlaces para lectura.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Alfredo. Aqui no se presentan ejemplos o enlaces. Aqui se ayuda a resolver dudas ya trabajadas. Presentanos lo que has intentado y por qué ha fallado para poder ayudarte. Mira [ask] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Buenas noches, estimado Lois, entre a este foro por que necesito ayuda, estoy aprediendo, si me pregunta esta mal formulada tratare de mejorarla, pero si es de baja calidad, cual es el fin del foro, es ayudar a los que no sabemos o intercambiar ideas o conocimientos con las personas que ya los tienen. Muchas gracias de todas formas. Saludos

Comment: Hola Alfredo. Esto no es un foro. Mira el [tour] para entender como funciona este sitio y verás diferencias con la estructura de un foro. Por supuesto que la meta de este sitio es ayudar a gente con problemas, pero  las preguntas tienen que estar bien explicadas, segun [ask]. Por eso cuando preguntas, has de explicar que intentas, que has probado y por que no ha funcionado: errores, problemas, ... Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaracion y al resto del foro, por que aunque he preguntado mal en ocasiones, las repuestas que me han brindado me han servido de mucho. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que deberias evaluar es el proveedor que necesitas para cada caso, por ejemplo para `Mysql` necesitaras instalar el conector.

[Download Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

de esta forma no solo tendras las librerias sino ademas podras conectarte a la db desde el `Server Explorer` del Visual Studio

En el proyecto podrias agrerar la referencia por medio de `nuget`

[MySql.Data nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data)

despues el codigo sigue las reglas de `ado.net`

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?param1, ?param2)";  
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param1", TextBox1.Text);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param2", Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text));  

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

si conoces algo de ado.net es exactamente lo mismo

Para `postgresql` es bastante similar, necesitas las librerias de nuget

[Npgsql nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)

y despues el codigo

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    string query = "INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES (@p)";
    var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", "xx");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

la estructura es la misma, tienes ejemplos completos en el documentacion

[Npgsql Getting Started](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)

Comment: Gracias, Leandro, con SQL server yo hago una cadena de conexion, cuando me conecto a la base de datos, desde el proyecto, una vez instalado el conector de MySQL, funciona igual o no me presenta esa opcion.

Comment: es exactamente igual, solo que el connection string sera diferente en mysql, pero es la misma logica ya que estas utilizando ado.net y este es estandar para todas las base de datos

Comment: Hola Leandro. No es conveniente responder a pregutnas de baja calidad porque indirectamente se está "aceptando" este tipo de contenido. Un saludo

Comment: pero no es de baja calidad, es algien iniciando donde pide un empujon relacionado a conectarse a la db, una guia basica no cuesta nada darle, no se digo, pienso que ayudar es mas importante que la pregunta perfecta

Comment: Buenas noches, estimado Lois, entre a este foro por que necesito ayuda, estoy aprediendo, si me pregunta esta mal formulada tratare de mejorarla, pero si es de baja calidad, cual es el fin del foro, es ayudar a los que no sabemos o intercambiar ideas o conocimientos con las personas que ya los tienen. Muchas gracias de todas formas. Saludos